# In Flutter how do you update a page that you have navigated away from?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way of updating a page in flutter once you have navigated away from it?
So say I have page 1 which is a grid that has a bunch of thumbnail images that represent a list of my favorite images.
I click on one of the thumbnails and it takes me to another page that displays the image. On this page I click on a checkbox that removes it from my favorite images list. How can I then update the grid from the previous page to remove the image?

I don't have any code that I've tried because I'm fairly new to Flutter and I literally have no idea how to do it.

Comment: database to remember. https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

Comment: @P__J__ But closing page 2 doesn't update page 1, so I need a way to update it without reloading it

Comment: Can you add what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a database of some sort to handle your favorite pictures list.

Anyway you can return back the id/flag/favorite_status of the image to the first screen.

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.pop(context, iamgeId);
  },
  child: Text('Remove From Favorite!'),
);
```

In the first screen, remove the `imageId` from the list. and `setState`

Checkout [return data from a screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)  with an [interactive example](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data#interactive-example)